# Having a problem with the Room Db with Release build android Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-room

My data is not getting saved in the RoomDb Release build,
but my debug app is working fine with RoomDb.
Room Db was retrun in Kotlin class

Comment: did you add a new table to room?

Comment: yes I have added a new table but the entity class was not working in the release build

Comment: I Got solution just change in ProGraud by replacing the class name to .** { *; }, It working for me